# How do I create details for UITableViewCell while jumping to that detail after the button is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using *Xcode 8.2*, *Swift 3*, *iOS 10*.  I realize the title may be a difficult to understand so let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a `TabViewController` with three child `ViewControllers`, each with their own `NavigationController` and other stuff after that.  One such tab is shown below (Tab 1).  This is a `TableViewController` on which I'm showing my custom `TableView` *cells* with information.

[image]

On a different tab (e.g. Tab 2), I'm adding cells into Tab 1 on button click.  I have gotten this to work just fine.  Now, the behavior that I want is that when the user clicks that same button (on Tab 2), I want to add a cell (as before) but also add the details view of that cell and jump to that details view (instead of having to switch to Tab 1 and click the respective cell).  On this details view, I want there to be a **Back** button which will return me to Tab 1 which is where all the details views are accessed.

I have been trying to figure out the right way to achieve this behavior so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

**EDIT**

I made some edits based off of Winter's reply below.  However, I am still unable to "connect" the newly created `UIViewController` with a Table View cell.

I did the following:

In Tab 2:

```
// this code is located in a function where I call to create a new custom cell in Tab 1.  

//Switch to first tab
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

//Show the detail view
if let navigationController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController {
    let detailViewController = UIViewController()
    detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)

    let tempNavVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
    let resultsTab = tempNavVC.viewControllers[0] as! Tab1VC
    resultsTab.detailVCArray.append(detailViewController)
}
```

In Tab 1:

```
// this is an array that holds the newly created view controllers passed in from Tab 2
// when the user clicks on a cell, look up which cell it clicked on and display the view controller for that cell
var detailVCArray = [UIViewController]()

// called when a cell is clicked
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let newChildVC = detailVCArray[indexPath.row]
    self.addChildViewController(newChildVC)
    self.present(newChildVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I run it, the code in Tab 2 successfully executes and I am presented with a new View Controller with a red background.  However, if I click the Table View cell, it errors out:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller

instead of segueing to the same red View Controller.

I realize this is probably a really dumb way to do it but I can't think of anything else.

At the end of the day, I want my Tab 2 to create a Table View cell in Tab 1 that contains some View Controller with details and "transition" me to those details.

Comment: If you are creating cell info tab2 then you are having all the detail that you want to show it on detailView. Right?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `UISplitViewController`, not a `UITabViewController`.

Comment: Where is the code for adding the cell?

Answer (score 2):

The code is like this:

```
//Click function in viewController of Tab 2
func click(_ sender: Any) {
    //Adding cells into Tab 1

    //Switch to Tab 1
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

    //Show the detail view
    if let navigationController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
        let detailViewController = UIViewController()
        detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

//Code in viewController of Tab 1
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //For example: need to show detail view when row is 1
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        //Show the detail view
        let detailViewController = UIViewController()
        detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Winter.  This helps me out a lot but I am still trying to figure out how to "connect" that newly created View Controller to my Table View Cell.  I edited my original post.

Comment: You should use similar code in `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to display detail view.